# Fetch images from mySQL into 3D model in unity3d

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine, 3d, visualization

I have a project that needs to get images from MySQL DB and show it in 3D model in unity, the 3D model is shared on the same website, so I need to know how to get images dynamically and put it as a material on the model, not just fetching and put it at any place.

If anyone has any simple information please share it with me, thanks.

Comment: In what format are the models?  Maybe you could research MySQL data-types: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.php  A simple web front end to the database could fetch the model binary at (e.g.:) `https://blah.com/getModel?id=112233` and be fetchable via javascript AJAX.

Comment: hello, the models are generated from unity and shared on web hosting